# Cannot update: “Failed to get available update data.”

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8, drush

I cannot update some of the modules and the Drupal core itself from the "Available Updates" menu. The error is "Failed to get available update data. ".[image]

Comment: Do you see any additional info in your application/error logs?

Comment: @dbrumann no I am not getting any additional info

Comment: Please make sure that error_reporting and error_log are configured correctly. I don't think we can help without knowing _why_ it failed, i.e. the underlying error message.